# How to get the input date element value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input box of type = date, I want to capture the date value on change event.

Here is the code snippet

```js
function maintest() {
  input = $('<input>').attr({"type":"date"}).change(function() {
     alert(this.val());
  });
 $("#mainDiv").append(input); 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload ="maintest()">
  <div id="mainDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `$(this)` instead of `this`

Comment: Also note that the `change` event only fires on a date input once a valid date has been entered (ie. a day, month and year is selected)

Comment: If you want to use just `this` you can use directly `this.value` ( plain javaScript )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` is jQuery's method. Wrap it like this to get element's value:

```
$(this).val();
```

Comment: While this answers the question, you should add a code snippet to your answer so the solution is more visible and easy to ' test '. Especially in this case where the OP shared a Running code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to this

```html
function maintest() {
  input = $('<input>').attr({"type":"date"}).change(function(e) {
     alert(e.currentTarget.value);
  });
 $("#mainDiv").append(input); 
}
```

Comment: Or just `this.value`